# How to retrieve the first 10 elements in a template variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template I have a loop like this:

```
{% for member in blog.members.all %}
    {{ member.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to retrieve only the first 10 members and not all the members ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For full-scale paging, check out [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/). For simple slicing, check out the [`slice` filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice).

Answer (score 9):

```
{% for member in blog.members.all|slice:"10" %}
   {{ member.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```